# libpython2.6.so.1.0 doesn't exist

Tags: python, shared-library, gdb

I am trying to run an application called `powerpc-eabi-gdb`, however, when I start it, I get the following error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libpython2.6.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried to install `python2.6`. `apt-get` told me to install `python-gdbm` instead. I tried to install it and it seemed to be installed already.

What should I do now?

Comment: There are newer versions of `libpython` like 2.7 3.2 and 3.3 available, install those and try again.Also ensure that you are using correct architecture.Maybe installing the dbg symbols could help.

Comment: I don't think my `powerpc-eabi-gdb` accepts those newer Pythons, as it hasn't been updated for a long time. I am 100% sure I am using the correct architecture. I will try installing the `dbg symbols`.

Comment: version 2.6 is long ago out of support(and repo).You should give a try to atleast 2.7

Comment: I'm installing `python2.7` right now, hope it will work.

Comment: Let us know if it works or not

Comment: @AdityaPatil It finally finished installing it and no, it didn't work.

Comment: I don't think it will work because it is too old.You could try using an version 2.6 in **VM** by manually downloading and installing it there.

Answer (score 1):

The File you are trying to run is too old, will run only on `python2.6` which is not supported anymore.

You have following options

- Try and get newer supported version
- Use some old linux which uses `python2.6`
- install `python2.6` manually, recommended in Virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

Ugly, but working solution is to create symlink `libpython2.6.so.1.0` pointing to `libpython2.7.so`

```
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.6.so.1.0
```

Inspired with [Android bug report #37847](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37847).

Comment: easy solution .

Answer (score 0):

Picking up Aditya Patil's answer, you could grab possibly [Python 2.6.9](http://python.org/download/releases/2.6.9/), install it **locally** and use [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/virtualenv.html).